# Deceptive site ahead appeared only in chrome (asp core mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, google-chrome, google-search-console

i have a simple website with these pages

1. home index page
2. create page (after post, and when the client will be redirected to the index ,the deceptive site ahead appeared )

3)index page for these created files

and to know the create IActionresult method contains many things

- saving to the database,

- consuming an api from a shipment company to push the data in it .

- an instruction to send an email.

-Tempdata for data navigation between create and index

so does these thing related to the problem like make google understand that is phishing or something.
note: i am using a logo in my nav bar that is related to an online store and my website considers as a service for the owner of that online store.

[image]i searched on google transparency report for all my website links and this only what it says like the photo

and i made an owner verification on google search console and it detected that there is an issue but it doesn't gave me any URL samples that make this issue.

i am using smarterasp as hosting and msql,

Comment: _"it detected that there is an issue but it doesn't gave me any URL samples that make this issue."_ I think you're supposed to supply your own URLs to test.

Comment: hello phuzi, what do you mean by "you're supposed to supply your own URLs to test"

Comment: i cant put any url here because using the create page will generate an order  through the api of the shipment company

Comment: You're probably on your own then. We're not likely to be able to help you if we can't see what the pages are doing!